# How do I call an attribute using a list?

Tags: python

My goal is to call an attribute using the contents of a list.

The following is what I currently have, which works.

```
self.execute(record.last_modified, record.created)
```

My goal is the ability to change the words: "last_modified" and "created" using a list.

Here is my attempt 1, which returns an error saying the object has no such attribute.

```
my_list = ["last_modified", "created"]

self.execute(record.my_list[0], record.my_list[1])
```

My attempt 2:

```
my_list = ["last_modified", "created"]

one = str(my_list[0])

two = str(my_list[1])

self.execute(record.one, record.two)
```

The reason I'm doing this is because the contents of my_list will change in the future and I want the calls to change accordingly.

Comment: What is `record`? Make `record` a dictionary and use the strings as keys.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
my_list = ["last_modified", "created"]

one = str(my_list[0])
two = str(my_list[1])

# Assuming `self` and `record` are defined somewhere
self.execute(getattr(record, one), getattr(record, two))
```